# without auto layout ,how to use handle a single iOS storyboard file for 3.5 inch screen and 4 inch screen in my iPhone application

Tags: ios, ios5, ios7, storyboard

In my iphone application, I want to support from `iOS 5` for iOS 3.5 Inch and 4 Inch Screen using a single `iOS storyboard`.
 `Autolayout` came from `ios 6` onwards. I don't want to create a separate `storyboard` for iOS 3.5 Inch and 4 Inch Screen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set autosizing as shown in image then your button will appear in middle of the screen...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
 {

 }
 else
 {

  }
```

Comment: Rose, i am using StoryBoard for UI

Comment: So u can use autolayout

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone 3.5 Inch & 4 Inch support i think you must try Autosizing it will be also helpful.

Comment: harish mistry, can we handle if i need a button at middle of the screen with Autosizing.

Comment: Yes you can handle it too, for more details check my second anser